# best practice to create cloudwatch alarm to monitor amazon rds

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch

I know amazon provides awesome metrics for monitoring rds box, but my question is, if I only want to monitor whether it's reachable or not, like zabbix ping, what metric shall i use when creating an alarm?

Answer (score 1):

On the RDS console you can create event subscriptions, select events (like availability and failure) and assign notification groups.

I didn't find an option on cloudwatch to do this.